# JSONArray to list<object>

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a json string/array to an object list. jsonString is the raw string which I try to make into a jsonArray at the moment like so:

```
 List<Drink> drinks = new ArrayList<Drink>();
 JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

the string is:

```
 [{"alcohol":"Vodka","date":"2014-04-25T22:04:51","units":3.0},               
{"alcohol":"Beer","date":"2014-04-25T21:44:26","units":3.0}]
```

I don't really know how to progress from here,

any help would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the `JSONArray` and add to your drinks `List` like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonDrink = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String alcohol = jsonDrink.getString("alcohol");
    String date = jsonDrink.getString("date");
    double units = jsonDrink.getDouble("units");
    Drink drink = new Drink();
    // initialize drink object values here or in constructor (don't know what this class has)
    drinks.add(drink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the `JSONArray`, retrieve each `JSONObject` and call the appropriate `Drink` constructor from the object's attributes:

```
List<Drink> drinks = new ArrayList<Drink>();
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
int len = jsonArr.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String alcohol = obj.getString("alcohol");
    String date = obj.getString("date");
    double units = obj.getDouble("units");
    Drink drink = new Drink(alcohol, date, units);
    drinks.add(drink);
}
```

Of course, you may need to parse the date or do other data conversions before constructing your `Drink` object.

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray has toList() method. see https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#toList-- (I assume you use JSONArray form org.json)
your code should be like this

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
List<Drink> drinks = new JSONArray(jsonString).toList();
```